# Codeigniter doesn't let me update entry, because some fields must be unique

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

So what I'm trying to do:

1. Pull User data from database, including email address, username etc.
2. Edit it
3. Save it

But I want to keep username and email unique.
And for this I'm setting validation rules like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[15]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[15]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'required|matches[password2]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('group', 'User Group', 'required');
```

And as you can see I have `is_unique[users.username]` and `is_unique[users.email]` rules. But it doesn't let me update my entry using this rules.

So the question is, how can I update database entry, and keep those 2 fields unique(username and email)?

Comment: sorry i didn't get what exactly you want, is this case works fine with create user, and not working for edit user?

Comment: tip: before update check whether **UserName** and **Mail** already exist. if exist show error else update it. Game Over

Comment: @Naeem Yes, I can create new user with unique username and email, but at the same time I can't update this user, while still keeping same email and username i've entered when created new user

Comment: Have you tried behavior with other fields?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the call back validation function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_check_user_email');

function check_user_email($email) {        
    if($this->input->post('id'))
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    else
        $id = '';
    $result = $this->user_model->check_unique_user_email($id, $email);
    if($result == 0)
        $response = true;
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user_email', 'Email must be unique');
        $response = false;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

in model

```
    function check_unique_user_email($id = '', $email) {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        if($id) {
            $this->db->where_not_in('id', $id);
        }
        return $this->db->get('user')->num_rows();
    }
```

use same for the user name....

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 4

```
// is_unique[table.field,ignore_field,ignore_value]

$validation->setRules([
 'name' => "is_unique[supplier.name,uuid, $uuid]",  // is not ok
 'name' => "is_unique[supplier.name,uuid,$uuid ]",  // is not ok
 'name' => "is_unique[supplier.name,uuid,$uuid]",   // is ok
 'name' => "is_unique[supplier.name,uuid,{uuid}]",  // is ok - see "Validation Placeholders"

]);
```

Eg.

```
$validation->setRules(['email' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email,id,4]']);
// 'id' = ignore table field name (users table 'id' field) 
// '4' = ignore field value(currnet user id)
```

[codeigniter 4 validation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html)

For Codeigniter 3

1. Add following helper class (edit_unique_helper.php)

   function edit_unique($value, $params)  {
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->database();

   ```
   $CI->form_validation->set_message('edit_unique', "Sorry, that %s is already being used.");

   list($table, $field, $current_id) = explode(".", $params);

   $query = $CI->db->select()->from($table)->where($field, $value)->limit(1)->get();

   if ($query->row() && $query->row()->id != $current_id)
   {
       return FALSE;
   } else {
       return TRUE;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Add to autoload ()
3. Use edit_unique where you pass an extra parameter which is the id of the row you're editing
   eg. `$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|edit_unique[users.user_name.'.$id.']');`

[Source](https://github.com/ndt-draft/blog-ci/blob/master/application/helpers/edit_unique.php)