# Unique field in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.6

I need to make Unique Serial number SN in my form. I've tried to do it, but I can't understand how this function works. Please explain clearly as I'm new to programming with codeigniter

view:my view (form)

```
Branch: <input type="text"  name="branch" /><br/>
Business Unit: <input type="text"  name="buinessUnit" /><br/>
Device Type: <input type="text"  name="deviceType" /><br/>
Brand: <input type="text"  name="brand" /><br/>
Device Model: <input type="text"  name="deviceModel" /><br/>
SN: <input type="text"  name="SN" /><br/>  //that i need unique
status: <input type="text"  name="status" /><br/>
department: <input type="text"  name="department" /><br/>
username: <input type="text"  name="username" /><br/>
notes: <input type="textarea"  name="notes" /><br/>
computername: <input type="text"  name="computerName" /><br/>
Save:<input type="submit"  name="save" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

model:to insert data into database

```
<?php
class add_model extends CI_Model {

       public function insert_into_db(){
           $post=$this->input->post(); 
           //insert data with query builder
           $data=array('Branch'=>$post['branch'],'BusinessUnit'=>$post['buinessUnit'],'DeviceType'=>$post['deviceType'],'Brand'=>$post['brand'],'DeviceModel'=>$post['deviceModel'],'SN'=>$post['SN'],'Status'=>$post['status'],'Departmant'=>$post['department'],'UserName'=>$post['username'],'Notes'=>$post['notes'],'ComputerName'=>$post['computerName']);
           $this->db->insert('hardware_assets', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id(); // if using mysql
       }
}
```

controller:to handle model and view

```
<?php

class Speed extends CI_Controller {

        function insert_to_db()
           {
               $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
              $this->load->library('form_validation');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('buinessUnit', 'BuinessUnit', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('deviceType', 'DeviceType', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand', 'Brand', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('deviceModel', 'DeviceModel', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('SN', 'SN', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('department', 'Department', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('notes', 'Notes', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('computerName', 'ComputerName', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            /*   

           */
           if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
             {
                $this->load->view('pages/home');
             }
           else
             {
                 $this->load->model('add_model');
             $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
             $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view
            //$this->load->view('pages/formsuccess');
             }
           }

    // public function username_check($str)
    // {
        // if ($str == 'test')
        // {
            // $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            // return FALSE;
        // }
        // else
        // {
            // return TRUE;
        // }
    // }
}
```

Comment: set database column unique in which you want to store SN field value

Comment: cogeigniter 3 supports rule is_unique[tablename.field]

Comment: use SerialNumber for what ? For unique record storing and then to retrieve it according the id ? If so, you can ignore the Column of (SN), let the db help you to generate one.

Answer (score 1):

check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481955/codeigniter-doesnt-let-me-update-entry-because-some-fields-must-be-unique/30482479#30482479).

instead of user_name use serial no. it will work for both insert and update.

Comment: thank you for your help ,if you know how i can stop insert data when refresh page (duplicate)

Comment: that when i reload page ,it submit last data inserted again into database

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your this line,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('SN', 'SN', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

With,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('SN', 'SN', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[hardware_assets.SN]');
```

Comment: but with this solution how can i change message

Answer (score 0):

> If  you create your Own Function for UNIQUE SN then Used three Thing

```
$date = date("ymdhis");
 $SD = rand(10,2000);
$ID =$this->db->insert_id();
$SN = $ID.SD.$date;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Making Your Custom validation please add a file in your library folder my_form_validation.php as you can modify this function or create new one as per your requirement,

```
    <?php

    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
        //used to check unique value at update record
        function unique($value, $params) {
            $CI = & get_instance();
            $CI->load->database();
            $CI->form_validation->set_message('unique', 'The %s is already taken.');
            list($table, $field, $id_field, $id) = explode(".", $params, 4);

            $data = $CI->db->select($field)->from($table)
                            ->where($field, $value)
                            ->where($id_field . " != ", $id)
                            ->get()->num_rows();
            if ($data) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
}
?>
```